# Setting facebook's profile picture as a LinearLayout background

Tags: android, facebook, background, uri, profile-picture

I have been trying with no avail to set my facebooks profile picture as a `Linearlayout` background in my application.
here are the two ways I tried to do this:

**first way:** got the uri from the profile picture and converted it to drawable

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    LinearLayout banner = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.banner);
       Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if(profile != null){
           // profile_pic_id.setProfileId((profile.getId()));
            Drawable d;
            Uri uri = profile.getLinkUri();
            //also tried profile.getProfilePictureUri(random_num,random_num)
            try {

                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                 d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, uri.toString());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_material);
            }
            banner.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        }
}
```

now this always threw an exception so the `Drawable` i get is the blue_material one (the `Drawable` set in the catch block), so if anyone knows why its throwing an exception all the time I'd be grateful.

**second way:** converted the `ProfilePictureView` to `ImageView` and then used `getDrawable()` on the `ImageView`.

```
 ProfilePictureView profilePictureFB=(ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.pic);
 profilePictureFB.setProfileId((profile.getId()));
 ImageView fbImage = ( ( ImageView)profilePictureFB.getChildAt( 0));
 banner.setBackgroundDrawable(fbImage.getDrawable());
```

now this resulted in having a background with the default picture facebook puts when someone has no profile pic.

**AND** whenever I use decodeStream an exception gets thrown.(example below)

```
URL img_url =new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.getId()+"/picture?type=normal");
                Bitmap bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());//bmp a bitmap
```

I didnt want to resort to asking this question on stackoverflow because I wanted to solve it myself, but I tried for so very long, so I had to get some help.

**Thanks for anyone who answers :)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I solved it!!**

i used imageLoader, and for some reason the url works with it, here is the code:

```
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if(profile != null){           
            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).build();
            imageLoader.displayImage("http://graph.facebook.com/" + profile.getId() + "/picture?width=400&height=400", imageView, options);
           // banner.setBackgroundDrawable(imageView.getDrawable());
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

the method `setScaleType` stretches my imageview across all my`LinearLayout`.
for more information about the universal image loader visit this link:
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure but this what i used to do

```
 img_url =new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+uname+"/picture?type=normal");
     bmp =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_url.openConnection().getInputStream());//bmp a bitmap
     linearlayout.setImageBitmap(bmp);//your linear layout
```

Comment: for some reason an exception gets thrown when the method decodeStream is called on my URL